# How to override Login Form for FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, overriding, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to override the login form of FOSUserBundle. I've seen on the web that you have to create new folders. So here's my project:

```
Intranet
 |___ templates
       |___ ApplicationFOSUserBundle
             |___ Security
                   |___ login.html.twig (the one that's supposed to override the other on)
```

But it doesn't work. I thought of changing directly in the SecurityController in the vendor, but of course I know that I can't do that.
I've also tried to create a Resources/views folders but same output, doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who wants to do the same, you actually have to override it like [that](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/overriding-default-fosuserbundle-templates/):

```
Intranet
 |___ src
       |___ Resources
             |___ FOSUserBundle
                   |___ views
                        |___ Security
                              |___ login.html.twig
```